# How to call JS setter function programatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a store class that has a model as such

```
class baseStore {
setValue(name, value) {
       this.model.setValue(name,value); 
       }
    }
class myStore extends baseStore{
   let model = {};
   get FirstName() { return this.model.FirstName;}
   set FirstName(firstName) { this.model.FirstName = firstName;}
```

I want my setValue to call the setter funciton, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not related to react. to trigger setter you need to just assign the value `this.FirstName = value;`.

Setters and getters are functions that get executed when value is used like normal property. And you need to do this in method or constructor if you want on init

```
class baseStore {
    setValue(name, value) {
       this[name] = value;
    }
}
class myStore extends baseStore{
   let model = {};
   get FirstName() { return this.model.FirstName;}
   set FirstName(firstName) { this.model.FirstName = firstName;}
}
```

Comment: In runtime I dont have that information, I am using a baseclass for all my stores to setValue of their model. I updated the quesiton desc

Comment: @Pacman  I've updated my answer, you basically set property on this and it will trigger setter if name is `'FirstName'` or it will update normal property on instance otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use method to set `key-value` on model you can do this.

```js
class myStore {
  constructor() {
    this.model = {}
  }

  setValue(name, value) {
    this.model[name] = value;
  }
}

var store = new myStore;
store.setValue('foo', 'bar')
store.setValue('foo1', 'bar1')


console.log(store)
```